# Delete columns in mysql with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

I have to delete from a table only the columns, not the entire rows, using `where` through two tables.
Here is an example :

```
delete from Rating using Movie, Rating 
where Movie.mID=Rating.mID 
  and Rating.stars<4 
  and (Movie.year<1970 or Movie.year>2000);
```

This query works but in the table `'Rating'` it deletes the entire row. I want to delete only the data in the column `'stars'`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your table to do that. you actually need to update the value of the column `stars` may bo to `NULL`

```
 Update stars set NULL // and go on with your query
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `update` statement but no `delete`:

**Change**:

```
delete from Rating using Movie, Rating 
where Movie.mID = Rating.mID 
  and Rating.stars<4 
  and ( Movie.year < 1970 or Movie.year > 2000 );
```

**To**:

```
Update Rating r, Movie m
set r.stars = 0
where m.mID = r.mID 
  and Rating.stars < 4 
  and ( m.year < 1970 or m.year > 2000 );
```